# Tsv file parser for c++ ends abruptly when empty cell is present

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse a .tsv file and store the values of each cell of the row in a struct. Each row forms the struct and is appended to a list. If a cell is empty the `getline` while loop ends abruptly

The .tsv file looks like this:

```
No Name Age Grade
1   Andy 17   A
2   Drew 16   B
3   Brad 17   B
4   Cam       A
5   Sam  18   B
```

Sample code

```
std::ifstream tsvFile(filePath);
if (!tsvFile.good()) return;
for (std::string line; std::getline(tsvFile, line); )
{
  example item;
  tsvFile >> example.s_no >> example.name >> example.age >> example.grade;
  tsv_list.push_back(item);
}
tsvFile.close();
```

Loops through all rows and not stop abruptly.Is there a better way to parse a tsv line by line and add a specific tab delimiter ? I tried using `line` but the value doesn't seem correct. Printing `line` gives me an integer number and not the entire row every time I iterate through.

Comment: Unrelated nitpicking: Usually all [delimiter-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) files are still called [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files, no matter the actual separator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example for reading records from a file.

We will choose an Object Oriented Approach and put all data into a struct, and, since the struct should know how to read and write its data, add an extractor and inserter opererator.

The extractor will read a complete line and then put the data into the structures member. In case of an errror, default values can be used.

In main, we just define a vector of Roster and use the range constructor, to read the complete input file during the variable definition.

Afterwards, we print the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// Test Data. Same as reading from file
std::istringstream testFile(R"#(1   Andy 17   A
2   Drew 16   B
3   Brad 17   B
4   Cam       A
5   Sam  18   B
)#");


struct Roster
{
    // Roster Data
    size_t No{};    std::string Name{}; size_t Age{};   char Grade{};

    // Extractor operator >> for Roster
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Roster& r) {

        std::string line{};             // Here we will store the read line
        std::getline(is, line);         // Read complete line
        std::istringstream iss(line);   // Copy to a istringstream for extraction
        if (!(iss >> r.No >> r.Name >> r.Age >> r.Grade)) {     // Extract
            // In case of error: Reset all values
            r.No = 0; r.Name = "ERROR"; r.Age = 0; r.Grade = '#';
        };
        return is;
    }
    // Inserter operator << . Print space delimited data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Roster& r) {
        return os << r.No << ' ' << r.Name << ' ' << r.Age << ' ' << r.Grade;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Read complete CSV
    std::vector<Roster> roster{ std::istream_iterator<Roster>(testFile), std::istream_iterator<Roster>() };

    // Copy all data to output
    std::copy(roster.begin(), roster.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Roster>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```